# pine script different strategy.exit

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm having a hardtime to have two different `strategy.exit`. One for the take profit and other to the Trailing Stop Loss. The strategy works fine if I put both in the same `strategy.exit` line, but  I want two different labels on the chart, on for the TP and other to the TSL. If I put two `strategy.exit`, only Take profit work.

```
// Get inputs
atrLength = input.int(title="ATR Length", defval=21, minval=1)
useStructure = input.bool(title="Use Structure?", defval=true)
lookback = input.int(title="How Far To Look Back For High/Lows", defval=9, minval=1)
atrStopMultiplier = input.float(title="ATR Multiplier", defval=0.85, minval=0.1, step = 0.05)
// Calculate data
atr = ta.atr(atrLength)
lowestLow = ta.lowest(low, lookback)
highestHigh = ta.highest(high, lookback)
longStop = (useStructure ? lowestLow : close) - atr * atrStopMultiplier
shortStop = (useStructure ? highestHigh : close) + atr * atrStopMultiplier
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ATR Trailing Stop Loss --------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Take Profit -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
longProfitPerc = input.float(title="Long Take Profit (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01
shortProfitPerc = input.float(title="Short Take Profit (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01
// Figure out take profit price
longExitPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + longProfitPerc)
shortExitPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - shortProfitPerc)
// Submit exit orders for take profit
if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.exit(id='Long STOP', limit=longExitPrice, alert_message="close BTCUSDT a=usdm")
    strategy.exit(id = 'L - TSL', stop = longStop)
if strategy.position_size < 0 
    strategy.exit(id='Short STOP', limit=shortExitPrice, alert_message="close BTCUSDT a=usdm")
    strategy.exit(id = 'S - TSL', stop = shortStop)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have one `strategy.exit()` and use the `comment_profit` and `comment_loss` properties of the `strategy.exit()`.

```
strategy.exit(id='Long Exit', limit=longExitPrice, stop = longStop, alert_message="close BTCUSDT a=usdm", comment_profit="Long - TP", comment_loss="Long SL")
```